# Unknown network "development"

Tags: truffle, mist, networkid

I installed truffle globally. I'm trying to connect truffle to a localhost

```
truffle console
> migrate
```

It failed with `Unknown network "development". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks.`.

`truffle.js` and `truffle-config.js` ( why there are two files  ? )

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 9545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rename truffle-config.js to truffle.js.

Comment: Changing the filename did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have port 9545. Was that intended? The default port is 8545 for testrpc.

Try confirming on which port you started your network and make sure it is still alive.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }`

This is the default `truffle network`.